# Is there a way to listen for events on the pop up manager class?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to detect when pop ups are visible (including tool tips if possible). The reason is that I need to hide or freeze (capture a snapshot) the Stage* components (StageWebView, StageVideo, StageText etc) when pop ups appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no really easy way to achieve this. What you can do is this:

- create a custom popupmanager
- make it dispatch events on the Application, so you can listen anywhere
- tell Flex to use your class instead of the default implementation

**Create a custom PopupManager**

We create a custom PopupManager class to which we can add some custom functionality. In your case it might for instance be interesting to dispatch an event on the Application, so that we can listen to it from everywhere on the displayList. We'll be extending PopUpManagerImpl which is the default implementation used by Flex.

```
public class MyPopupManager extends PopUpManagerImpl {

    private static var instance:IPopUpManager;

    static public function getInstance():IPopUpManager 
    {
        if (!instance) instance = new MyPopupManager();
        return instance;
    }

    override public function addPopUp(
        window:IFlexDisplayObject, 
        parent:DisplayObject, 
        modal:Boolean=false, 
        childList:String=null, 
        moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory=null):void 
    {
        super.addPopUp(window, parent, modal, childList, moduleFactory);
        var app:IEventDispatcher = 
            IEventDispatcher(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);
        app.dispatchEvent(new Event("popupAdded", true));
    }

}
```

We override the addPopup method to dispatch a bubbling event whenever a popup is shown. Ignore the getInstance() method for now. I'll get back to that later. What you do need to know is that FlashBuilder will not automanage some of your imports because these classes were marked as hidden. Nothing to worry about but you'll have to write the import statements manually for:

```
import mx.managers.IPopUpManager;
import mx.managers.PopUpManagerImpl;
```

**Tell Flex to use your class instead of the default implementation**

This would be fairly easy:

```
import mx.core.Singleton;
Singleton.registerClass("mx.managers::IPopUpManager", MyPopupManager);
```

The only problem is that Flex has already registered an implementation and you can't override it, even if you execute this on 'preinitialize'. So we'll have to do it before Flex starts bootstrapping. We'll use a custom preloader for that:

```
public class RegisteringPreloader extends DownloadProgressBar {

    override public function initialize():void {
        super.initialize();
        Singleton.registerClass("mx.managers::IPopUpManager", MyPopupManager);
    }

}
```

DownloadProgressBar is the default Flex preloader. We just add the extra registering code. Now don't forget to tell your application to use this preloader:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               preloader="RegisteringPreloader" >
```

**Now just listen for the event**

```
addEventListener("popupAdded", onPopupAdded);
PopUpManager.addPopUp(new Panel(), this);
```

**Extra info**

Now why does MyPopupManager have to have a static getInstance() method? Well that's because that Singleton class we used to register our implementation, expects every class it registers to be a singleton and hence to have a method called 'getInstance'. It will try to call this method and will crash if it doesn't exist. If you don't know what a singleton is, just google. You'll find tons of information.

PS: I actually learnt something new trying to solve this question (thanks for that).

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I could help you learn something new. ;) You are right. This approach is the way to do it but it is out of scope for this feature. What about listening for the systemManager addChild or addedToStage events? Is the systemManager numOfElements or numOfChildren bindable? I could bind the visibility to systemManager.numOfElements<1?

Comment: In your learning do you know if Singleton.registerClass works for any class? Can I use it for my own evil purposes?

Comment: One more comment to add. The open declaration doesn't work for PopUpManager as it points to the implementation so this is great you have found this info.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Q1: I don't thinks so. I can't think of a way that you would know that whatever object was added to the displaylist is actually added as a popup. Q2: Yes, you can. It is in essence just a dictionary of interfaces and their singleton implementations. Just get an implementation you've registered by calling `Singleton.getInstance("path.to::MyInterface")`. Just make sure the implementation has a `getInstance()` method.

Comment: Thanks. I think then I would have to check if the added object was a UIComponent and check the property isPopUp? Though, I don't know if that is set by the PopUpManager or if you have to set it yourself.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you're right. The `PopUpManagerImpl#addPopUp()` method sets the `isPopUp` property of the popup to `true` (line 334 in the SDK 4.6 version). So that approach might work.

Answer (score 0):

For my `Spark` `Application` I had to make a few other modifications to RIAStar's answer. My custom class was not found in the `preloader.initialize()` yet ( `ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition()`) so I added an event listener for the `PRELOADER_DOC_FRAME_READY` event.

```
package com.mydomain.preloaders {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    import mx.core.Singleton;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import mx.preloaders.SparkDownloadProgressBar;

    public class RegisteringPreloader extends SparkDownloadProgressBar {

        public function RegisteringPreloader() {

        }

        public var preloaderSprite:Sprite;

        override public function set preloader(value:Sprite):void {
            super.preloader = value;

            preloaderSprite = value;

            value.addEventListener(FlexEvent.PRELOADER_DOC_FRAME_READY, preloaderCompleteHandler);

        }

        protected function preloaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
            var myCustomClass:Class;
            var classPath:String;
            var hasDefinition:Boolean;

            preloaderSprite.addEventListener(FlexEvent.PRELOADER_DOC_FRAME_READY, preloaderCompleteHandler);

            classPath = "com.domain.managers::MyClassImpl";
            hasDefinition = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition(classPath);

            if (hasDefinition) {
                myCustomClass = Class(getDefinitionByName(classPath));

                Singleton.registerClass("mx.managers::ISingletonClass", myCustomClass);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the steps are the same as RIAStar's.