# Alter ResourceManager to split values by semicolon, not comma

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4, resourcebundle

As the title says, is there a way to alter the ResourceManager's `getStringArray()` in a way that it splits the resources by semicolon, not comma?

The actual method can be found in the `ResourceManagerImpl` class, which can be found in in the package `mx.resources`.
Overriding that method would be fine, but ideally I'd like to write my own `getStringArray` with a variable separator, however, there seems to be no way of extending either the `ResourceManager` or `ResourceManagerImpl` class to somehow add that method.

Anyone got a clue what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you can't extend `ResourceManagerImpl` since it's not `final`, but rather that you have to be able to register your implementation with the application instead of the default one. And doing this is a bit tricky.

So first create your implementation:

```
public class MyResourceManager extends ResourceManagerImpl {

    private static var instance:IResourceManager;

    static public function getInstance():IResourceManager
    {
        if (!instance) instance = new MyResourceManager();
        return instance;
    }

    override public function getStringArray(bundleName:String,
                                            resourceName:String,
                                            locale:String = null):Array {
        //do your stuff
    }

}
```

So we've overriden the `getStringArray` method. Notice that we've done the same for `getInstance`, because we want it to return a new instance of `MyResourceManager` instead of `ResourceManagerImpl` (we don't have to mark `override` because it's a `static` method). Also, you may have to write some import statements manually, because some of the classes you're using are marked as 'excluded'.

Now we have to tell Flex to use `MyResourceManager` instead of `ResourceManagerImpl`. We can do this with the following code:

```
import mx.core.Singleton;
Singleton.registerClass("mx.resources::IResourceManager", MyResourceManager);
```

The problem is that we have to do this before Flex registers `ResourceManagerImpl`, because you can't override it once it's registered. For this we need to create a custom preloader in which we do the registering (sadly, the Application's 'preinitialize' phase is not early enough).

```
public class RegisteringPreloader extends DownloadProgressBar {

    override public function initialize():void {
        super.initialize();
        Singleton.registerClass("mx.resources::IResourceManager", 
                                MyResourceManager);
    }

}
```

Now assign the custom preloader to the application and we're done:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               preloader="RegisteringPreloader" >
```

For further info I refer you to a fairly similar, but somewhat more elaborate answer that I wrote for a different question: [Is there a way to listen for events on the pop up manager class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034020/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-events-on-the-pop-up-manager-class)

Comment: Wow, I most certainly did not expect such a detailed answer! Thank you very much indeed for your help. I'll get to it right away. Might just use the `RegisteringPreloader` class for some other loading stuff that I'm currently doing in the app's preinit phase. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, after some tiny adjustments (I took the liberty to edit your code accordingly [hope you can see the edit comment]), I'm hanging with the actual implementation of the ResourceManager. When I try to call my getStringArrayBySeparator function, I get an error 1061 (undefined method). The variable declaration is as follows: `var _resourceMan:IResourceManager = MyResourceManager.getInstance();` and the call of course `_resourceMan.getStringArrayBySeparator'.

Comment: Ok, I figure I can't add my own method because the method isn't actually defined by the IResourceManager interface, hence isn't found. Suppose overriding the getStringArray method with my own would only be possible if I don't add another variable because of the same reason. Although it would be a nice feature, I could do with the simple override and just change the comma to a semicolon.

Comment: @Al_Birdy Thanks for the edit. I think using variables shouldn't be an issue, as long as you don't want to expose them and keep them internal.

Comment: Sure, using variables is fine, but I meant adding another parameter to the getStringArray method won't work (obviously). Nevertheless, I've got this working with a variable now. Works very well. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Al_Birdy Come to think of it: you could also simply do `resourceManager.getString(..., ...).split(';')` ;)

Comment: F... me! Casting that to an Array and there we go. Works like a charm. Time to re-write it once again. ;) Naturally it is much nicer this way. I really appreciate your input! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: if you want to provide your localization with array of strings containing commas, it is way easier to use `getObject` method of `IResourceManager`.

In your properties file:

```
my.beloved.strings: ["That's it, string one", "Okay, string two"]
```

In your code:

```
var strings:Array = _resourceManager.getObject(_bundleId, 'my.beloved.strings') as Array;
var stringOne:String = strings[0];
```

You don't have to override anything this way.