# How to get popup's parent used in PopUpManager.addPopUp()

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I want to make a parent of my popup dispatch events when open and close popup

```
[MessageHandler(type="events.MyEvent",selector="newClient",messageProperties="data")]
public function newClientMessageHandler(data:Object):void{

    var parent:Sprite = data.parent; 
    // Component that have to dispatch event

    // Dispatch "open" event
    parent.dispatchEvent(new MyEvent('dialogOpen'));

    var newDialog:ClientsDialog = new ClientsDialog();
    newDialog.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, onCloseDialog);
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(newDialog, parent, true);
}

protected function onCloseDialog(event:CloseEvent):void{

    var dialog:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;

    // here i want to "parent" dispatch "close" event something like
    dialog.parent.dispatchEvent(new MyEvent('dialogClose'));

    // but dialog.parent is not the same as "parent" in upper function
    // how do i get that "parent" used in PopUpManager.addPopUp?

    dialog.removeEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, onCloseDialog);    
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(dialog);

}
```

How do i get that "parent" used in PopUpManager.addPopUp(newDialog, **parent**, true);

Comment: Store a reference on the class scope (assuming these two methods live in the same class).

Comment: Thanks for idea. I did even better. I wrote my own PopUpManager, which store references to displayed popups and their parents and dispatches events. Is any idea how to replace regular PopUpManager with new one, instead of replacing all occurrences in application?

Comment: Yep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034020/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-events-on-the-pop-up-manager-class/9034994#9034994